# inputs in methods at visual c# 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arrays, methods

I am facing a problem in creating a console application in Visual Studio c# 2005

I created the following program in which a method (to sum 2 predefined values) is called in the program

here is the code of it

```
class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        program a;
        a = new program();
        Console.WriteLine(a.am1(1,2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    int sum;
    public int am1(int num1, int num2)
    {
        sum = num1 + num2;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Now here is the main problem I am facing, well in this program two integers (num1 and num2) are predefined, I wanted those 2 numbers to be taken from user, means user input the two numbers and then the same program goes on like above. How it should be done?

P.S remember everything should be done in methods

Comment: please format your code the next time!

Comment: As well as the answer provided of using the program arguments (args[]) you can interact with the user using the Console and the Console.ReadLine() method which: Reads the next line of characters from the standard input stream.

Comment: @David Hall: depending on the ui, you could also interact with the user via textBoxes and alikes :)

Comment: @Andreas true :) actually, I just noticed that the OP used ReadLine() their original question so my comment was a bit superfluous. I was trying to help out given that the OP appears to have very basic C# knowledge. Very helpful answer by the way.

Comment: @David: was that sarcasm? ... heard it ... somehow :)

Comment: @Andreas - not a word of sarcasam there - the answer was great, which is why I upvoted it.

Comment: @David: sorry, your comment wasn't brutal enough :) glad that you like it!

Answer (score 2):

i hope i got your requirements ... if not, please elaborate!

```
public sealed class Program
{
    private readonly int _number1;
    private readonly int _number2;

    public Program(int number1, int number2)
    {
        this._number1 = number1;
        this._number2 = number2;
    }

    public int Sum()
    {
        return this._number1 + this._number2;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // this one here is really brutal, but you can adapt it
        int number1 = int.Parse(args[0]);
        int number2 = int.Parse(args[1]);
        Program program = new Program(number1, number2);
        int sum = program.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

sry, this is not my main coding style ... pfuh ... really ugly!

edit:

1. don't give blind trust in `int.Parse()`. the params are coming from the user, you better double check them!
2. you better triple check them, as you are doing a sum ... thankfully c# compiles with `unchecked` - this code may fail with an `OverflowException` if compiled in vb - remember ranges of `int`
3. why do you want to do a simple addition in an extra class?
4. you should elaborate your style (regarding your comment): separate ui-code from business-layer code!
5. you do not need to create an instance variable for each task - you can do that with scope variables too...!
6. ...

Comment: Whose coding style is it? Do you mean that you don't normally write in C#?

Comment: nope :) ... i normally do not adapt to the style of the OP ... but this one here was so brutal ... wow ... reminds me of my first days :)

Comment: woah.. its so brutal.. man several things in your given code i don't have learned yet. make it easy please

Comment: brutal is the word of the day :) what is your level at c#? so i can adapt my answer...

Comment: class Program
    {
        int sum;
        public int am1(int num1, int num2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1st Value:");
            num1 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("\n Enter 2nd Value:");
            num2 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            sum = num1 + num2;
            return sum;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program a;
            a = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine(a.am1(1, 2));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

Comment: @Aliza: you should adapt your question, not add another comment here :) ... and: this is really bad coding style, as you are interacting with the console in a business-layer function ....

Answer (score 0):

Use console application command line arguments. If it suites you. Below is an example from MSDN.

```
 public class Functions
    {
        public static long Factorial(int n)
        {
            // Test for invalid input
            if ((n < 0) || (n > 20))
            {
                return -1;
            }

            // Calculate the factorial iteratively rather than recursively:
            long tempResult = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                tempResult *= i;
            }
            return tempResult;
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Test if input arguments were supplied:
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument.");
                System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: Factorial <num>");
                return 1;
            }

            // Try to convert the input arguments to numbers. This will throw
            // an exception if the argument is not a number.
            // num = int.Parse(args[0]);
            int num;
            bool test = int.TryParse(args[0], out num);
            if (test == false)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument.");
                System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: Factorial <num>");
                return 1;
            }

            // Calculate factorial.
            long result = Functions.Factorial(num);

            // Print result.
            if (result == -1)
                System.Console.WriteLine("Input must be >= 0 and <= 20.");
            else
                System.Console.WriteLine("The Factorial of {0} is {1}.", num, result);

            return 0;
        }
    }
    // If 3 is entered on command line, the
    // output reads: The factorial of 3 is 6.
```